# i am working in MVC and i am getting this error in jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery

I don't know that what am i missing in this code... that i am getting this error... 
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

i am getting all the values in editvalue function in my VIEW i.e

```
@foreach (var item in Model.spGetAllJudgments)
{
<button onclick="editValue('@item.judgementid', '@item.date', '@item.judgementfile', '@item.comments', '@item.citation', '@item.findings', '@item.casetypeid', '@item.courtid', '@item.userid', '@item.caseid');" type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
Edit
</button>
}
```

and my javascript function is given as

```
<script>
function editValue(judgementid, date, judgementfile, comments, citation, findings, casetypeid, courtid, userid, caseId)
{
debugger;
$('#judgementid').val(judgementid);
$('#date').val(date);
$('#comments').val(comments);
$('#citation').val(citation);
$('#findings').val(findings);
$('#casetypeid').val(casetypeid);
$('#courtid').val(courtid);
$('#userid').val(userid);
$('#caseid').val(caseId);
}
</script>
```

Comment: "I don't know that what am i missing in this code"  Based on the error message, I'm *pretty* sure what you're missing is a close paren. Check the line number on the error message to see where it is (it doesn't appear to be in the code you've presented here.)

Answer (score 1):

First, I highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

Personally I'm not a fan of inline javascript.  It makes debugging incredibly difficult IMHO.  Although I don't see an error in your code, I would rewrite your code into:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.spGetAllJudgments)
{
<button type='button' 
        class='btn btn-info js-editvalue' 
        data-toggle='modal'
        data-target='#myModal'
        data-judgementid='@item.judgementid'
        data-date='@item.date'
        data-judgementfile='@item.judgementfile'
        data-comments='@item.comments'
        data-citation='@item.citation'
        data-findings='@item.findings'
        data-casetypeid='@item.casetypeid'
        data-courtid='@item.courtid'
        data-userid='@item.userid'>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
Edit
</button>
}
```

with script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.js-editvalue').on('click', function(e) {
  {
    var $element = $(e.currentTarget);
    debugger;
    $('#judgementid').val($element.data('judgementid'));
    $('#date').val($element.data('date'));
    $('#comments').val($element.data('comments'));
    $('#citation').val($element.data('citation'));
    $('#findings').val($element.data('findings'));
    $('#casetypeid').val($element.data('casetypeid'));
    $('#courtid').val($element.data('courtid'));
    $('#userid').val($element.data('userid'));
    $('#caseid').val($element.data('caseId'));
   });
});
</script>
```